# Add Authorization at the beginning or the end of production?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, authorization

In the production process of an internal-use ASP.NET/C# website, are there any advantages to starting with authentication/authorization/login FIRST, and building up from there?  Or is it better to just build your site exactly how you want it, with unlimited restrictions and no logins or anything, and then do that at the end of production, before release?  That's what I WANT to do --- just work on the functionality of the website, unrestricted, having one less thing to worry about.  But I want to make sure that this approach doesn't cause problems later.

When it comes time to implement the ASP.NET authentication, it should just be a matter of running the script to generate the necessary tables and then using WSAT to manage the users and then provide restrictions to the already-existing content...should be...

Comment: when you have opportunity to build it completely, then buid with security. who knows without restriction how the application will become. "Before software can be reusable, it first has to be usable"

Comment: Do?es that mean security first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give your security consideration right up front. Even if you don't develop the final login screens and restrict access as you develop, IMO you should make sure that you can authenticate your users and limit access on at least one screen before going ahead with 'god mode' development. Include:

- Authentication - Windows, Forms, etc.
- Authorization / Access Control - will Role do or do you need Operation-level checking - e.g. AzMan
- If you will be using SiteMap, you will need to look at security trimming to hide functionality to which the user doesn't have access (menus, breadcrumbs etc)
- Auditing - e.g. changes to important data

Even though the site is for internal use, users can't be trusted, and you will need to ensure that you are safe from SQL Injection, XSS etc as well.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely yes, that is the practical approach. You, said it, adding security creates no problem at all to an existing project. 
Infact, when you come to securing the site there are a number of procedures before creating users. Also you shouldn't rely fully on WAT for user management it is better, I think, to have your own interface as you'll need it after deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach may sound faster but it have architectural drawbacks in following areas:

1- Missing security alignment with per page / per method level invocation.

2- Not clear Use case and work flow in terms of authentication / authorization.

3- Complete lack of security based testing while developing and adding up the new features gradually.

4- Lack of End-to-end dependency- What if security needs to be considered across layers, you will miss the whole vision on modular dependency and end-to-end testing.

Overall, if you do it 1st then you can just have one sample user/pwd/roles established and use that for all the secure areas of site, this will be sufficient to test and develop the application continuously.

Later when your application is ready; it's good to go with large number of user/pwd and associated roles to work with.

Hope this helps.